# How to use a class variable in a function?

Tags: python, class

First of all I apologize if I have writen some word incorrectly -  English is my second language.

But anyway I've been working on an text RPG for like a week and just started on an combat system and I have all of the player and enemy statistics in clases.

This is just part of my code but it's enough. So I have made a function which levels up my character.

```
class player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name='Hero'
        self.lvl=1
        self.xp=0
        self.lvl_next=25
        self.str=1
        self.dex=1
        self.int=1

    def pl_level(self):
        Nstr=0
        Ndex=0
        Nint=0

        while player.xp>=player.lvl_next:
            player.lvl+=1
            player.xp-=player.lvl_next
            player.lvl_next=round(player.lvl_next*1.5)
            Nstr+=1
            Ndex+=1
            Nint+=1

        print('Level:', player.lvl)
        print('STR {} +{} DEX {} +{} INT {} +{}'.format(player.str, Nstr, player.dex, Ndex, player.int, Nint))
        player.str+=Nstr
        player.dex+=Ndex
        player.int+=Nint
        print('Exp: '+str(player.xp))
        print('To the next level: {}%'.format(int((player.xp/player.lvl_next)*100)))
        print('Next:', player.lvl_next)
```

But I don't know why it just does not work.
I've tried to simplify my code because well maybe thats how i'll find the problem. But it just keeps shoving me this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\2XK_\Coding\Python\Python_Battle\Ulfberht\leveling_system.py", line 99, in <module>
pl_level()
File "F:\2XK_\Coding\Python\Python_Battle\Ulfberht\leveling_system.py", line 11, in pl_level
while player.xp>=player.lvl_next:
AttributeError: type object 'player' has no attribute 'xp'
```

Even tho you can see that in **init** there is self.xp.

So how can I fix this?

Comment: Your code has gotten mangled (the indenting has changed) and is incomplete. Where does this "player" variable come from in your pl_level() function?

Please post a complete, runnable set of code, then somebody will be able to help you for sure.

Comment: You should use **self** instead of class name **Player**. Ex:  **self.xp** And you should pass self to each function in a class

Comment: Class names should follow the `CamelCase` style, variable and function names the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: I'm voting to close this, since the only issue was the lack of `self.` when using instance variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use that like `self.px` inside other methods or else if you want to use like that only make it `player().px` instead of `player.px`.As your class needs to be to initialized first before using any of its variables or methods.

Better to access class variables in same class by using `self` as good practice.